# How to show equivalence of permutations

Tags: group-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number and let $S_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

If $\rho \in S_n$, I am to show that:

$\rho(1,2,...,n)\rho^{-1} = (\rho(1),\rho(2),...\rho(n))$

But I don't know how to calculate the left hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\tau$ for $(1\ 2\ \cdots\ n)$. This means that $\tau$ is the mapping from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to itself with $\tau(i)=i+1$ except that $\tau(n)=1$.

Define
$\sigma=\rho\tau\rho^{-1}$. Let's see how $\sigma$ acts on $\rho(i)$.
By definition
$$\sigma(\rho(i))=\rho(\sigma(\rho^{-1}(\rho(i))))=\rho(\sigma(i))=\rho(i+1)$$
unless $i=n$ (that's an exercise for the reader). This means that
$\sigma$ takes $\rho(i)$ to $\rho(i+1)$. In cycle notation
$$\sigma=(\rho(1)\ \rho(2)\ \cdots\ \rho(n).$$